# /dev/xvda1 full , though there is no temporary files

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, udev

I have AWS ec2 micro instance, suddenly it shows memory full. I have checked the folder using `df -h`command. The result is displayed below.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  7.1G  257M  97% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            285M  8.0K  285M   1% /dev
tmpfs            59M  184K   59M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            295M     0  295M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

I have cleared all the temporary folder,log files but still it shows the same size.Why this happening? How to delete the unwanted files? and increase the space?

Comment: Well...are you using all that space? It doesn't look "full" ...and by memory, do you actually mean disk space? Micro instances have a very small RAM allocation.

Comment: Try a du -sh /* to see where the disk space is being used and post up the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On CLI type:

```
 lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'
```

that processes have some reources allocated and u can free them killing them by pid

```
kill -9 [pid]
```

after this check your disc usage with:

```
df -h
```

Comment: use sudo before lsof

Comment: that seems to work, but never try on production system :P